# is there a state management solution for lit-element?

Tags: polymer, lit-element

If there is a list which should be rendered from an array, and the array will be passed from the grand-grand-grand-grand-grand-parent custom element. That will be super annoying.

Is there a global state management solution for `lit-element`, just like `redux`?

Answer (score 9):

[LitElement](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/) is a library and you can use any library for state management that you want. Just subscribe to the store in the `constructor` or `connectedCallback` (unsubscribe in `disconnectedCallback`) and change the components' properties when the store notifies you of a change.

Here you have some PWA helpers that works with litElement and you have one for Redux.

https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-helpers#connect-mixinjs

Answer (score 9):

Yes, check out [LitState](https://github.com/gitaarik/lit-state) (npm package name `lit-element-state`).

I created this specially for LitElement. It has the same mindset: simple, small and powerful.

Because it is created specially for LitElement, it integrates very well and therefore the usage is very simple. You make a state object like this:

```js
import { LitState, stateVar } from 'lit-element-state';

class MyState extends LitState {
    @stateVar() myCounter = 0;
}

export const myState = new MyState();
```

*Usage without @decorators, [look here](https://gitaarik.github.io/lit-state/build/#basic-usage/no-decorator-usage/).*

Then you can use the state in your components like this:

```js
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
import { observeState } from 'lit-element-state';
import { myState } from './my-state.js';

class MyComponent extends observeState(LitElement) {

    render() {
        return html`
            <h1>Counter: ${myState.counter}</h1>
            <button @click=${() => myState.counter++}></button>
        `;
    }

}
```

When you add the `observeState()` mixin to your component, the component will automatically re-render when any `stateVar` they use changes. You can do this with any amount of component and states and it will all automatically stay synchronized thanks to the `observeState()` mixin.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but get `Cannot assign to read only property 'counter' of object '#<DemoState>'
    at new DemoState (demo-state.js:11:22)` - do you happen to know if there is a working example somewhere?

Comment: Hi @habibg, there are instructions on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/gitaarik/lit-state) and there's also [documentation](https://gitaarik.github.io/lit-state/build/). If you have any issues, please open an [issue at the GitHub Page](https://github.com/gitaarik/lit-state/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) which is an extremely popular framework independent state management library

*"MobX is unopinionated and allows you to manage your application state outside of any UI framework. This makes your code decoupled, portable, and above all, easily testable."* - ([Github](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx))

Answer (score 1):

I am late in the game, but this can be quite usefull:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lit-app/state

@lit-app/state is a global state management, integrating with lit web-components.

### Why a new state-management tool ?

There are plenty options available for state management, so why yet another one?

- Some existing options are too heavy. In my opinion, managing state should be lean and simple. Redux, for instance falls into this category.
- Some solutions designed for lit (for instance [lit-state](https://github.com/gitaarik/lit-state)) do not support Typescript and do not take advantage of lit@2 Reactive Controlers, very well suited for hooking external features into templating lifecyce.
- Some elegant ideas were worth pursuing (for instance [this tweet](https://twitter.com/passle_/status/1528318552947806212), or [this post](https://dev.to/pfrueh/the-dom-eventtarget-interface-6ak).

### How to use it?

```
import { State, StateController, property } from "@lit-app/state";
import { LitElement } from "lit";

// declare some state
class MyState extends State {
  @property({value: 'Bob'}) name  
}
const myState = new MyState()

// declare a component
class StateEl extends LitElement {

  // StateController is a Reactive Controller binding myState with the element
  state = new StateController(this, myState)
  override render() {
    return html`
      <div>This will be updated when the state changes: ${myState.name}</div>
    `;
  }
}

// changing the state will reflect in the template
myState.name = 'Alice'
```

Comment: Good job, man. I noticed the lit ecosystem had grown very slowly during the past three years.

Comment: Nice one. Are you able to provide a non-TS version of it?

Comment: What is that @property garbage?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has created [lit-mobx](https://github.com/adobe/lit-mobx) now and is probably using it for the new online version of Photoshop to use the [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) state management framework easily with lit.

You can read more of them using lit components here: [Photoshop is now on the web](https://medium.com/@addyosmani/photoshop-is-now-on-the-web-38d70954365a) but there is no mention about how they actually do state management.